# Twitter REST API check for suspension

Tags: twitter, twitter-rest-api

When a user's Twitter account is suspended, user can still sign in with his/her Twitter account.

REST API doesn't give any information about the suspension.
If user makes a `GET friends/ids`, no error code comes. Only empty friends list.

Is there a way to understand a signined user's suspension state ?